# Notification of changes in Core Data SQLite store between iPhone and Apple Watch app

Tags: ios, core-data, watchkit, apple-watch

I have an iPhone (iOS 8) and Apple Watch (watchOS 1) apps that share their data using Core Data (SQLite store, placed in shared app group). Both apps are using the same data access code that is placed in shared framework. `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is being set up in the following way:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    let sharedContainerURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(self.sharedAppGroup)!
    let storeURL = sharedContainerURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(self.databaseName)
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        fatalError("Unable to add persistent store: \(error)")
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

From my understanding, in runtime each app has its own `NSPersistenStoreCoordinator` instance (as iPhone apps and WatchKit extensions do have completely separate address space), but these two connect to exactly the same SQLite database file.

How can an iPhone app be notified when Watch app changes some data in the common SQLite store and the other way around: how can a Watch app be notified when the iPhone app changes some data in the common persistent store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I've found quite satisfactory was to use [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) library.

It works by using CFNotificationCenter Darwin Notifications and writing/reading data files in the shared app group, which results in instant communication between an iOS app and an app extension (Watch app, today's widget, etc).

Basic code goes like this:

- Wormhole initialization

  ```
  wormhole = MMWormhole(applicationGroupIdentifier: appGroup, optionalDirectory: nil)
  ```
- Passing data object to a wormhole

  ```
  let payload = ["Key": "Value"]
  wormhole.passMessageObject(payload, identifier: theSameMessageIdentifier)
  ```
- Listening for incoming object from a wormhole

  ```
  wormhole.listenForMessageWithIdentifier(theSameMessageIdentifier) { message -> Void in

      if let payloadDictionary = message as? Dictionary<String, String> {
          // Do some work
      } 
  }
  ```

It's as simple as that.

Comment: This library probably implements ideas which Marcus S. Zarra mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily.  There is no way to send a direct communication between the two applications.

My current recommendation in this regard is to use files on disk that include the objectIDs of anything that has changed from one app to the other.

When you detect a save to disk you write a file that, for example, is JSON and includes up to three arrays: update, insert, delete.  The file name should be some form of timestamp.

Separately you should be watching the directory for any files created by the other app and consume them.  Load the ObjectIDs and then create a notification out of the ala iCloud or in iOS 9 a remote notification.  Then delete the file after process.

On launch, remove all files from the other store since you will automatically be aware of anything that happened pre-launch.

Not simple but fairly straight forward.